# Find index of regex match in string

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to find the index of a match in regex while still getting the match? For example:

```
str = "foo [bar] hello [world]"
str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/) { |match,idx| 
  puts match
  puts idx
}
```

Unfortunately, `idx` is nil in this example.

My real world problem is a string, where I want to replace certain sub strings, that are wrapped in brackets with parentheses, based on some conditions (e.g. if the string is inside a blacklist), e.g. `"foo [bar] hello [world]"` should become `"foo [bar] hello (world)"` when the word `world` is in a blacklist.

Comment: Further to a suggestion by Eric Duminil, I have refactored my code. Since you accepted my answer (thanks btw), be sure to check the update:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
blacklist = ["world"]
str = "foo [bar] hello [world]"

str.gsub(/\[(\w*?)\]/) { |m|
  blacklist.include?($1) ? "(#{$1})" : m
}

#=> "foo [bar] hello (world)"
```

Comment: @eric I have implemented your suggestion re the matching groups. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want an Enumerator with every match object, you can use :

```
def matches(string, regex)
  position = 0
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    while match = regex.match(string, position)
      yielder << match
      position = match.end(0)
    end
  end
end
```

As an example :

```
p matches("foo [bar] hello [world]", /\[(.*?)\]/).to_a
# [#<MatchData "[bar]" 1:"bar">, #<MatchData "[world]" 1:"world">]
p matches("foo [bar] hello [world]", /\[(.*?)\]/).map{|m| [m[1], m.begin(0)]}
# [["bar", 4], ["world", 16]]
```

You can get the matched string and its index from the match object.

But actually, it looks like you need [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a block:

```
"foo [bar] hello [world]".gsub(/\[(.*?)\]/){ |m| # define logic here }
```